# error while trying to write to `/var/app/ondeck/.bundle/config`, AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my rails 5.0 app to EB following the Amazon guide. I also used the webpacker config file

(https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/blob/master/docs/additional-reading/elastic-beanstalk.md) to resolve webpacker issues.

However, now it seems like it isn't able to compile the assets?

From the log:

```
Compilation failed:
There was an error while trying to write to /var/app/ondeck/.bundle/config. It
is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh 
failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

While doing an init, I also got the following error:

```
Note: Elastic Beanstalk now supports AWS CodeCommit; a fully-managed source control service. To learn more, see Docs: https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/
Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit? (y/N) (default is n): n
ERROR: IOError ::
```